# The stdio filter crashed when piped

Tags: c, string, stdio

I have written a program to anagram string using strfry. It works greatly with default standard input, but crashes when used with stdio redirection(functions, but segfaults at the end):

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "sys/mman.h"

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fryend=stdin;
    if (argc==1) goto mainloop;
    if (argc>1) fryend=fopen(argv[1],"r") ? fryend : stdin;

    mainloop:;
    char *buf=malloc(4096);
    while (!ferror(fryend)) {
        memset(buf,0,4096);
        strfry(fgets(buf,4095,fryend));
        fputs(buf,stdout);
    }
    free(buf);
    if (fryend!=stdin) fclose(fryend);
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong here? Used GNU libc/GCC. Run through valgrind and no memory leak detected.

Comment: Your `fgets` call works always on `stdin`. If `fryend` is a file, you should `fclose` it, otherwise Valgrind will complain. I'm not sure how `strfry` behaves on `NULL` input. I think it is cleaner to separate the `fgets` and `strfry` calls and check for `NULL`.

Comment: As a side note: Having a failed `fopen` silently fall back to `stdin` is not a good design, in my opinion.

Comment: @M Oehm:It is a stdio filter, like `rev`, so it is reasonable to have fall back to `stdin`.

Comment: Well, maybe. With all the changes you have made to the original code in the meantime, do you still observe the same behaviour?

Comment: Good observation. Changing `fgets(buf,4095,stdin)` into `fgets(buf,4095,fryend)` should have made a difference....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fgets` returns `NULL` when the end of the file has been reached. You should use this return value rather than calls to `ferror` or `feof` to control your loop. You should also be careful not to pass `NULL` pointers to string functions. They might handle this gracefully, but usually don't.

So your loop should look like:

```
while (fgets(buf, 4096, fryend)) {
    strfry(buf);
    fputs(buf, stdout);
}
```

I've thrown out the `memset`, because the result of `fgets` is null-terminated and will not overflow the buffer, so you can pass the full 4096 byte length.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite this line

```
if (argc>1) fryend=fopen(argv[1],"r") ? fryend : stdin;
```

without the conditional operator.

Maybe something like

```
if (argc > 1) {
    FILE *tmp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (tmp) fryend = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When redirecting `stdin`

```
a.out <test.txt
```

`fgets()` might return `NULL`.

From [man `fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> [...] fgets() return[s] [...] NULL on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read.

In turn `NULL` gets passed to `strfry()`,

```
strfry(fgets(buf, 4095, fryend));
```

which isn't a good idea.